# How to redirect the previous page in JSP via servlet

Tags: jsp, button, servlets

I have a form to create user in jsp. There are 2 buttons named for Save and Cancel  While I click "Save" button, user is saved into the database.It works. My problem I want to mention is not to redirect to previous page(list_users.jsp). How can I do?

Here is my code shown below.

user_forum.jsp

```
<button type="reset" name="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
```

Servlet

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String button = request.getParameter("button");

        if("Save".equals(button)) {
            createUser(request, response);
        }
        else if("Cancel".equals(button)) {  --> not working 
            String page = "list_users.jsp"; 
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#buttonCancel").click(function() {
            history.go(-1);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`response.sendRedirect("list_users.jsp");`

Answer (score 1):

i think when you click on rest button its not hitting servlet.

for that inside your form user No need of button , just use 
`<a href="servletmappingurl?button=Cancel">rest</a>`  request with a simple anchor and a request parameter reset witch says that the button should be reset button=cancel.

and add the below code in your servlet it will resolve your problem

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String button = request.getParameter("button");

        if("Cancel".equals(button)) {  --> not working 
            String page = "list_users.jsp"; 
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
```